# Gmail API with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gmail

Пытаюсь построить приложение используя gmail api на react. Для авторизации использую [библиотеку](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login) "react-google-login",

```
 export default class App extends Component {
  service = new Service();

  render() {
    const responseGoogle = (response) => {
      this.service.getMessagesList();
    }
    return (
      <div>
          <GoogleLogin
    clientId="YOUR_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    buttonText="Login"
    onSuccess={responseGoogle}

  />
```

после авторизации пытаюсь через fetch получить список своих email используя google api https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list
Но сервер возвращает мне 401 ошибку.

код моего фетч запроса

```
 export default class Service {
    _apiBase = "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me";
    async getResource(url) {
      const res = await fetch(`${this._apiBase}${url}`);
      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Could not fetch ${url}, received ${res.status}`);
      }
      const body = await res.json();
      return body;
    }

    getMessagesList = async () => {
      const list = await this.getResource(`/messages`);
      return list;
    };
```

Ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Специальное значение `me` может использоваться для указания аутентифицированного пользователя. Однако код ответа на статус ошибки  401 - указывает, что запрос не был применен, поскольку ему не хватает действительных учетных данных для целевого ресурса, попробуйте передать туда `userId` вместо указания `me` и посмотрите, что придет в ответ.

Comment: @DenisBubnov сам логин с помощью библиотеки происходит, в консоли мне возвращает мои данные гугл-аккаунта, логин, пароль, куча всяких аксес токенов и юзер айди. Но я не понимаю где мне их использовать. А в документации ничего найти не могу.
И скажите пожалуйста что значит "передать хидере запроса в блоке Authorization"  не совсем понимаю. 
Все апи до этого были простыми с простой документацией. Где без проблем всё получала, даже если токен регистрировать надо было. А здесь уже два дня по 8 часов сижу и ничего не получается, не понимаю.

Comment: @DenisBubnov спасибо, почитаю. Вот ошибка.
https://i.gyazo.com/bbdb33797c152032b8ed46fe74bfb2dd.png

Comment: Насколько я понял, все оказывается просто. Вы авторизовались - это конечно же хорошо, но чтобы пользоваться Google API - необходимо на основании полученных авторизационных данных сконфигурировать API, чтобы можно было выполнять команды. Вот тут есть пример, почитайте: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js  Нельзя просто так взять и отправить запрос через `fetch` и думать, что все будет работать :)

Comment: Дополню еще одной ссылкой: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js собственно я про это уже говорил, что для начала в  Google API Console создаем себе API key посредством которого будем юзать API. нельзя передавать `me` в `userId`, если вы не сконфигурировали API, в таком случае из полученных данных нужно достать `userId` и положить вместо ключевого слова `me`

Comment: @DenisBubnov оформите Ваш комментарий как ответ

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach увы, но фидбэка от автора не последовало, а в комментариях лишь рекомендации, я понимаю, что они могут быть полезны, но они не дают конкретного ответа на вопрос. Хотя, в каком-то роде ответ всё же есть. Я надеялся, что автор вопроса предоставит свой вариант ответа после решения проблемы.

Comment: @DenisBubnov Ваш комментарий в принципе является ответом, а также это помогло бы в решении [этого вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8646/%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%95%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0)

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach хорошо, постараюсь в ближайшее время оформить в виде развернутого ответа. Чтобы было полезно не только автору вопроса, но и другим участникам, столкнувшимся с похожей проболемой.

Answer (score 0):

Специальное значение `me` может использоваться для указания аутентифицированного пользователя. Однако код ответа на статус ошибки `401` - указывает, что запрос не был применен, поскольку ему не хватает действительных учетных данных для целевого ресурса, попробуйте передать туда `userId` вместо указания `me` и посмотрите, что придет в ответ.

Если Вы авторизовались - это конечно же хорошо, но чтобы полноценно пользоваться **Google API** - необходимо на основании полученных авторизационных данных сконфигурировать API, чтобы можно было выполнять команды. Вот тут есть пример: [Browser Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js). Код из примера:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Gmail API Quickstart</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Gmail API Quickstart</p>

    <!--Add buttons to initiate auth sequence and sign out-->
    <button id="authorize_button" style="display: none;">Authorize</button>
    <button id="signout_button" style="display: none;">Sign Out</button>

    <pre id="content" style="white-space: pre-wrap;"></pre>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Client ID and API key from the Developer Console
      var CLIENT_ID = '<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>';
      var API_KEY = '<YOUR_API_KEY>';

      // Array of API discovery doc URLs for APIs used by the quickstart
      var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest"];

      // Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
      // included, separated by spaces.
      var SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly';

      var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize_button');
      var signoutButton = document.getElementById('signout_button');

      /**
       *  On load, called to load the auth2 library and API client library.
       */
      function handleClientLoad() {
        gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
      }

      /**
       *  Initializes the API client library and sets up sign-in state
       *  listeners.
       */
      function initClient() {
        gapi.client.init({
          apiKey: API_KEY,
          clientId: CLIENT_ID,
          discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
          scope: SCOPES
        }).then(function () {
          // Listen for sign-in state changes.
          gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

          // Handle the initial sign-in state.
          updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
          authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
          signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick;
        }, function(error) {
          appendPre(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
        });
      }

      /**
       *  Called when the signed in status changes, to update the UI
       *  appropriately. After a sign-in, the API is called.
       */
      function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
          authorizeButton.style.display = 'none';
          signoutButton.style.display = 'block';
          listLabels();
        } else {
          authorizeButton.style.display = 'block';
          signoutButton.style.display = 'none';
        }
      }

      /**
       *  Sign in the user upon button click.
       */
      function handleAuthClick(event) {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
      }

      /**
       *  Sign out the user upon button click.
       */
      function handleSignoutClick(event) {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
      }

      /**
       * Append a pre element to the body containing the given message
       * as its text node. Used to display the results of the API call.
       *
       * @param {string} message Text to be placed in pre element.
       */
      function appendPre(message) {
        var pre = document.getElementById('content');
        var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
        pre.appendChild(textContent);
      }

      /**
       * Print all Labels in the authorized user's inbox. If no labels
       * are found an appropriate message is printed.
       */
      function listLabels() {
        gapi.client.gmail.users.labels.list({
          'userId': 'me'
        }).then(function(response) {
          var labels = response.result.labels;
          appendPre('Labels:');

          if (labels && labels.length > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
              var label = labels[i];
              appendPre(label.name)
            }
          } else {
            appendPre('No Labels found.');
          }
        });
      }

    </script>

    <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
      onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
      onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Нельзя просто так взять и отправить запрос через `fetch` и думать, что все будет работать. Необходимо сконфигурировать Google API со своими `Client ID` и `API key`, взятыми из консоли разработчика гугл.

Дополню еще одной ссылкой: [Google API Client Libraries (JavaScript) - Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js). Собственно, я про это уже говорил, что для начала в Google API Console создаем себе API key посредством которого будем использовать API (нужно будет зарегистрировать свое приложение и в настройках получить по окончании ключ). Если вы не сконфигурировали API, то работать он не будет. Нужно сконфигурировать API, а потом после авторизации из полученных данных доставать `userId` и передавать в запросах.